# How to change the size of an icon in Material UI 4.0?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried with `fontSize` and with `height` and `width` but it doesn't work.

Example:

```
/*Component code */
    <Tooltip title="Disminuir cuotas">
          <IconButton
            className={clsx(classes.quotaIcons, classes.minusIcon, {
              [classes.quotaIconsRight]: buttonsToTheRight
            })}
            size="small"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => handleBillingsNumber('minus')}
          >
            <RemoveIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
/*Component code */

    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      quotaIcons: {
        fontSize: 32,
        color: theme.palette.primary.main
      },
      minusIcon: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
      },
      quotaIconsRight: {
        fontSize: 8
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fontSize="inherit"` prop in your icon component from `@material-ui/icons`, then the way we can see above will work.

```
<RemoveIcon fontSize="inherit"/>
```